# display elements of a specific categorie on jsp

Tags: jsp

> i create this code (categorie.jsp) that display a liste of categories which have an ID,NAME,and two actions : update and delete..each categorie contains products

```
    <table border="1" width="25%" cellpadding="5">


                <tr style="color:white;">
                    <td ><center><b>Id</b></center></td>
                    <td><center><b>Title</b></center></td>
                    <td ><center><b>Actions</b></center></td>
                </tr>
                <%
                ClientDAO cd = new ClientDAO();
                PreparedStatement pr = (PreparedStatement)cd.method_Connection().prepareStatement("select * from categorie");
                ResultSet rs = pr.executeQuery();
               %>
               <%  while (rs.next()){ %>
            <tr>    
              <td ><center><b> <%=rs.getInt("id_cat") %></b></center></td>
              <td><center><b><%=rs.getString("name_cat") %></b></center></td>

              <td ><center><b>
                       <a href ="CategorieContent.jsp" >update</a> &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp
                       <a href ="#">delete</a>
              </b></center></td>

           </tr>    
           <% } %> 

     </table>
```

when i clique on UPDATE it will forward to another jsp page (products.jsp).how can i get the id of the choosen categorie and display it on the page products.jsp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass id as query string to jsp page when you click on update. Fetch this id on products.jsp page

**categorie.jsp**

```
        <td>
            <center>
                <b> <a href="products.jsp?id=<%=rs.getInt("id_cat") %>">update</a> &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp
                    &nbsp <a href="#">delete</a>
                </b>
            </center>
        </td>
```

**products.jsp**

```
<%
   String id=request.getParameter("id"); 
// Fetch products with this Category id
 %>
```

Comment: Thank you so much ... you helped me a lot